# fatal error: json-c/json.h: No such file or directory Cross compiling on ubuntu x64 for raspberry pi arm

Tags: c, linux, gcc, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile my code on my Ubuntu x64 laptop for the Raspberry Pi.

I am able to compile and run the code on Ubuntu laptop without any issue. However when I try to compile it for Raspberry Pi I get the following error:

```
$make
/home/nmohan/Development/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -I /home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/inc -fPIC -shared -L/home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/Obj_arm -Wl,-rpath=/home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/Obj -o  /home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/Obj_arm/libRSXA.so /home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/lib/RSXA.c -lNMT_stdlib -lNMT_log -ljson-c -lc  -Ljson-c
/home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/lib/RSXA.c:11:25: fatal error: json-c/json.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:101: recipe for target '/home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/Obj_arm/libRSXA.so' failed
make: *** [/home/nmohan/github/NiRobot/Obj_arm/libRSXA.so] Error 1
```

```
#---------------------------------------#
#                                       #
#            Global Varibles            #
#                                       #
#---------------------------------------#
PROJ_DIR    = /home/nmohan/github/NiRobot
BIN_DIR     = $(PROJ_DIR)/bin
OBJ_DIR     = $(PROJ_DIR)/Obj
OBJ_DIR_ARM = $(PROJ_DIR)/Obj_arm
INC_DIR     = $(PROJ_DIR)/inc
LIB_DIR     = $(PROJ_DIR)/lib
OUT_DIR     = $(PROJ_DIR)/bld
OUT_DIR_ARM = $(PROJ_DIR)/bld_arm
CFLAGS      = -g -Wall -Wextra -I $(INC_DIR)
SFLAGS      = -fPIC -shared
RPATH       = -L$(OBJ_DIR) -Wl,-rpath=$(OBJ_DIR)
RPATH_ARM   = -L$(OBJ_DIR_ARM) -Wl,-rpath=$(OBJ_DIR)
GCC_DIR     = /home/nmohan/Development/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc

#---------------------------------------#
#                                       #
#              Targets                  #
#                                       #
#---------------------------------------#
OBJS        = NMT_stdlib.so \
              NMT_log.so \
              RSXA.so \
              PCA9685.so \
              MTDR.so \
              CAM_MOTOR_CTRL.so \
              HCxSR04.so

#---------------------------------------#
#                                       #
#            Dependancies               #
#                                       #
#---------------------------------------#
NMT_STDLIB_LIBS     = -lc

NMT_LOG_LIBS        = -lc \
                      -lNMT_stdlib \

RSXA_LIBS           = -lNMT_stdlib \
                      -lNMT_log \
                      -ljson-c \
                      -lc 

PCA9685_LIBS        = -lNMT_stdlib \
                      -lNMT_log \
                      -lc \
                      -lwiringPi \
                      -lcrypt \
                      -lm \
                      -lrt \
                      -lRSXA

MTDR_LIBS           = -lNMT_stdlib \
                      -lNMT_log \
                      -lwiringPi \
                      -lPCA9685 \
                      -lcrypt \
                      -lm \
                      -lrt \
                      -lRSXA

CAM_MOTOR_CTRL_LIBS = -lNMT_stdlib \
                      -lNMT_log \
                      -lwiringPi \
                      -lMTDR \
                      -lPCA9685 \
                      -lcrypt \
                      -lm \
                      -lrt \
                      -lRSXA


HCxSR04_LIBS        = -lNMT_log \
                      -lNMT_stdlib \
                      -lRSXA \
                      -lwiringPi \
                      -lcrypt \
                      -lm \
                      -lrt

TARGET_OBJS := $(foreach OBJ,$(OBJS),$(OBJ_DIR)/lib$(OBJ))
TARGET_OBJS_ARM := $(foreach OBJ,$(OBJS),$(OBJ_DIR_ARM)/lib$(OBJ))

all: $(TARGET_OBJS) \
     $(TARGET_OBJS_ARM)
.PHONY: all

$(OBJ_DIR)/lib%.so: $(LIB_DIR)/%.c $(INC_DIR)/%.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(SFLAGS) $(RPATH) -o  $@ $< $($(*)_LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR_ARM)/lib%.so: $(LIB_DIR)/%.c $(INC_DIR)/%.h
    $(GCC_DIR) $(CFLAGS) $(SFLAGS) $(RPATH_ARM) -o  $@ $< $($(*)_LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/lib%.so: $(LIB_DIR)/%.cpp $(INC_DIR)/%.hpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SFLAGS) $(RPATH) -o  $@ $< $($(*)_LIBS)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on  json-c/json.h. You need to include these files that were not found.

Comment: How do I provide that file? If I dont cross-compile I have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Installing libjson-c-dev package.

```
sudo apt install libjson-c-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. It's because of the json.h which is not part of the, in my case, gcc-arm-10-3-2017.07...-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.
I simply cloned json-c git and compiled it with the cross-compiler, too. Then you can reference to the output, or you can inlcude the whole git into your project and compile it all in one.